# How to tell eclipse NOT to validate pom.xml without changing pom.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, jacoco

My pom.xml is fine and I can do a mvn clean install without a problem but eclipse paints it red and complains about:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.5.10.201208310627:prepare-agent (execution: default, phase: initialize)   pom.xml /super-project  line 11 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

How do I just tell eclipse to forget about the pom.xml, in other words, not to try to compile it, validate it, etc. so my project does not have errors and it is not painted in red?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a similar problem in the past where eclipse doesn't like a plugin in the pom. The solution i've found is to use plugin management.  An example from my own code is:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
            only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>
                                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                                </groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    maven-dependency-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange>
                                    [2.6,)
                                </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>
                                        copy-dependencies
                                    </goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

It's messy, but it also prevents future devs from having the same headaches.

[official m2e page](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) has a way to ignore them if you are running 4.2 Juno

Comment: It gotta be some other way without changing the POM. Like I said in my question I cannot change the POM just to fix my IDE. Other people are using other IDEs. :(

Comment: Try the suggestions in this url then http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered If you are using 4.2 it appears you can ignore lifecycles locally.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/javacountdown/issues/66.
Eclipse issue!